# Windows Phone 8 - HowTo display current position on the map

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, maps

As the title suggest I am struggeling with the display of the current location of the user on the map.

Afaik there a two ways to display the current user location:

1. In Code: create a ellipse, set it as content of a `MapOverlay`, set the GeoCoordinate of the MapOverlay, add this overlay to a `MapLayer` and add this to the map - but I cannot access the `MapOverlay` anymore and thus I cannot change (update) the position of the user.
   **Is there a way to update the user position without having to redraw all the map layers?**
2. XAML and Code: In Windows Phone 7 I was able to add a `Pushpin` to the map and let the `GeoCoordinateWatcher` handle the `PositionChanged` event and set the `MyLocation.Location` to the current location.

It seems that there is no way to add a `Pushpin` to the map if you don't use the Windows Phone Toolkit. So I tried to add `Pushpin` from the Windows Phone Toolkit:

```xml
xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Maps"
xmlns:maptk="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Toolkit;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"

<maptk:Pushpin x:Name="MyLocation">

    <maptk:Pushpin.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Ellipse
                Width="15" 
                Height="15" 
                Margin="0" 
                Fill="SteelBlue" 
                StrokeThickness="1"
                Stroke="Black"/>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </maptk:Pushpin.Template>

</maptk:Pushpin>
```

But I cannot access the MyLocation pushpin in my MapPage.xaml (the debugger says it is `null`).

**Can I display and update the current user position on the map with `maptk:Pushpin`?**

In Windows Phone 7 I could simply create a XAML layout for the pushpin which would hold the user location like this:

```xml
xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps"

<maps:Map Grid.Row="2" x:Name="Map" >

    <maps:Pushpin x:Name="MyLocation" >
        <maps:Pushpin.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Ellipse Width="12" 
                         Height="12" 
                         Margin="0" 
                         Fill="SteelBlue" 
                         StrokeThickness="1"
                         Stroke="Black"
                         />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </maps:Pushpin.Template>
    </maps:Pushpin>

</maps:Map>
```

then I could add a `GeoCoordinateWatcher` which would listen for the `PositionChanged` event and change the `Location` of the MyLocation pushpin:

```cs
void GeoCoordinateWatcher_PositionChanged ( object sender, GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate> e )
{
    MyLocation.Location = e.Position.Location;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way,

```
Pushpin pushpin = new Pushpin();

pushpin.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);

pushpin.Location = new GeoCoordinate(Latitude, Longitude);

pushpin.Content = "SampleString";

pushpin.Width = 25;

map1.Children.Add(pushpin);//this is way add pushpin to map
```

Have visited this one .

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/3d95b0c5-5f48-4918-b761-f8302fa090c2/updatehow-to-show-pushpin-on-microsoftphonemapscontrolsmap#bbb42943-663b-41f1-a920-f7368f2fee70

Comment: How do I update the position if the GeoCoordinateWatcher fires the PositionChanged event?