# The type or namespace pushPin could not be found in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, maps, pushpin

When I'm trying to add a pushPin to map I am getting an error "The type or namespace pushPin could not be found in Windows Phone 8". Can anyone tell me what is the reference that I'm missing. I am using default maps by windows phone

Code that I'm using to add pushpin is as below.

```cs
MapLayer layer = new MapLayer();
Pushpin pp = new Pushpin();
pp.GeoCoordinate = MyGeoPosition;
MapOverlay overlay1 = new MapOverlay();
overlay1.Content = pp;
overlay1.GeoCoordinate = MyGeoPosition;
layer1.Add(overlay1);
myMap.Layers.Add(layer);
```

Thanks in Advance !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
MapLayer layer = new MapLayer();
Ellipse ellipse = new Ellipse();
ellipse.Width = 25;
ellipse.Height = 25;
ellipse.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(75, 200, 0, 0));
MapOverlay overlay1 = new MapOverlay();
overlay1.Content = ellipse;
overlay1.GeoCoordinate = MyGeoPosition;
layer1.Add(overlay1);
myMap.Layers.Add(layer);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: My requirment is to add the default pin

Comment: I have edited my answer, do check that & see if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Adding toolkit:MapExtensions.Children throws an error

Comment: then i would suggest you to create a usercontrol same as that of the default pushpin and use it.

Comment: What is the problem with default pin

Comment: as i told earlier that the new map control in windows phone 8.0 and 8.0 sdk itself made changes and didn't included the default pushpin class you use in windows phone 7. so third party toolkit added the pushpin functionality but now that support is not available either, so its better if you add your own user control instead of trying to add pushpin.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you've got these namespaces in your cs.

```
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps.Platform;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps;
using System.Device.Location;
```

and these references in your xaml:

```
xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Maps"
xmlns:maptk="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Toolkit;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
```

Change the xmlns:name according to your wish or if you've given it already change it.

Take a look over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18977613/windows-phone-8-howto-display-current-position-on-the-map)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: when i'm trying to use  Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps.Platform it is showing the type or name space name map does not exit

Comment: using this  Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Controls dont show any error

Comment: @user3252627 k so just take off the `Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps.Platform ` and see?

Comment: even for  Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps it shows same error

Comment: did you add those references which I mentioned to add in xaml?